# Start command in bat file create a zero byte log

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, command-line

I have used `Start` command (in command prompt) to concurrently execute some programs. I just used a command like this :

```
start time_calulation.pl > d:\Public\Sample-Programs\testlog.txt
```

- The program executes correctly, but `testlog.txt`log files has no data, it's a 0 (zero) byte file.
- With out `Start` the log file creates perfectly but I need to use `Start`.

Please anybody help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: What happens if you try : `perl time_calulation.pl > d:\Public\Sample-Programs\testlog.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

The start command from your post is telling Windows to do the following:  Use "start" to open a new command prompt, run the program "time_calulation.pl" in the new command prompt and pipe the STDOUT of the "start" command to the file "d:\Public\Sample-Programs\testlog.txt".

My first inclination would be to modify the Perl script to handle creating a log file.  Since you haven't shared the source code of that script, I'll provide a different solution.

First, create batch file (time_calulation.bat) that calls the Perl script and pipes the STDOUT of the Perl script into a file.  From your example, the batch file would contain:

```
perl time_calulation.pl > d:\Public\Sample-Programs\testlog.txt
```

One might be tempted to then just do something like this:

```
start time_calulation.bat
```

However, the newly opened command prompt doesn't go away.  I'm going to guess that you do want it to go away after running the Perl script.  This behavior is described in the help for the start command.  It refers to the /K option for cmd.exe.  If you look at the help for cmd.exe, there is a /C option to cause the command prompt to terminate.

So I believe the following will then do what you want:

```
start cmd.exe /C time_calulation.bat
```

This will open a new command prompt to run the batch file and will close that new command prompt after the batch file is finished.  And that batch file is running the Perl script and piping the STDOUT of the Perl script to a file.

Comment: if you introduce the `cmd` command, you can simply `cmd /c "perl time_calulation.pl > d:\Public\Sample-Programs\testlog.txt" (doesn't even need the `start` command) (note the quotes!)